# Strange C behavior involving static variable and fprintf

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I'm working on adding a feature to an existing large software tool (the tool is used for dns packet capture and parsing, etc.).  I noticed something strange in the original code and can't figure out what the explanation is.  The code has a struct for storing IP addresses (IPv6 and IPv4) as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int         af;  
    union {
        struct in_addr      a4;  
        struct in6_addr     a6;  
    } u; 
} iaddr;
```

Further, it has a function for converting addresses stored thusly into strings:

```
static const char * ia_str(iaddr ia) {                                  
    static char ret[sizeof "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff"];
    (void) inet_ntop(ia.af, &ia.u, ret, sizeof ret);
    return (ret);
}
```

Now, when printing packets, the code does something like this to print the source and destination address and port:

```
void output(const char *descr, iaddr from, iaddr to, ...
    ...
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u ", ia_str(from), sport);
    fprintf(stderr, "-> %s:%u", ia_str(to), dport);
```

So far, so good (I think).  This is published code and appears to work fine.  Now, when I make this tiny, tiny change, to simply combine the two above fprintf lines into one (this also happens if I try sprintf instead of fprintf) thusly:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u -> %s:%u", ia_str(from), sport, ia_str(to), dport);
```

The program prints the same address (i.e. the ia_str(from) address) in BOTH positions!

I'm stumped. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for framing the question well. I too was stumped once long back with inet_ntoa which uses a static buffer like your function ia_str(). You should also use the __thread modifier (if using Glibc) to seperate this buffer for multiple threads.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, but sizeof("abc") == 4. So, I don't believe you're correct; unless I misunderstood something.  user138645 thanks.  This project wasn't using Glibc, but I might end up using it, so that's good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because ia_str() is returning a pointer to a static buffer.

So, what happens is that both the calls to ia_str() are computed before the call to fprintf() is setup. The return value of ia_str() is pushed on to the stack, but because it is a static buffer, it contains the value that was last placed in there. Which just happens to be from is_str(from).

Comment: In other words, ia_str() is not reentrant +1

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious now, I feel dumb. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To fprintf the same address is being passed, since return from ia_str will return the same address in any number of invocation, only the last invocation's change will hold good. So when calling fprintf, the last called function ia_str(from) [function will be called from right to left] will modify ret, and only that will be present. It will be something like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u -> %s:%u", 0x12345, sport, 0x12345, dport);
```

Same address, so same value.

Comment: Thanks!  Well explained.  I'm accepting @Ziffusion's answer, because it was first, but yours is equally clear.  It seems obvious now. :-)